# Homology of a Polyhedral Complex

Tags: general-topology, matrices, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, manifolds-with-boundary

I am new to algebraic topology and have no experience at all in this field. I started reading Hatchers Book on algebraic topology, however i am still not able to fully understand the following paper by Leo Grady http://leogrady.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/grady2010minimal.pdf. More specifically i have trouble understanding page 6. I want to apply the results obtained in the paper linked to a polyhedral complex $K$ that is given as follows:

Imagine a cuboid and randomly choose points in its interior. Consider a Voronoi Diagram inside the cuboid using the standard euclidean norm. This procedure yields a polyhedral complex with the following elements:

- The 0 cells ($C_0(K)$) inside this complex correspond to the vertices of the resulting polyhedrons
- The 1 cells ($C_1(K)$) correspond to the 1 dimensional faces (edges) of the resulting polyhedrons
- The 2 cells ($C_2(K)$) are the facets of the resulting polyhedrons which we consider twice in 2 different orientations
- The 3 cells ($C_3(K)$) are the resulting polyhedrons

Orient the edges arbitrarily but fixed. Consider each 2-dimensional face in 2 orientations. The 3-dimensional cells consist of the facets of the resulting polyhedron in both orientations.

I understood why the matrix $B$ defined as $B_{i,j} := \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if edge } a_i \text{ and facet } f_j \text{ are incident and coherent,}\\
-1 & \text{if edge } a_i \text{ and facet }f_j \text{ are incident and anti-coherent,}\\
0 & \text{else}\\
\end{cases} $

is the boundary operator $\partial^K_2$ of the following chain complex:

$\cdot\cdot\cdot \xrightarrow{\partial^K_4} C_{3}(K) \xrightarrow{\partial^K_3} C_{2}(K) \xrightarrow{\partial^K_2} C_{1}(K) \xrightarrow{\partial^K_1} C_{0}(K) \longrightarrow 0$

Now, i have the following question:

- How does the incidence matrix C corresponding to $\partial^K_3$ look like? According to the paper i thought of something like this: $C \in \{0,-1,1\}^{2 \cdot \#facets \times \#polyhedrons}$ , where $C_{i,j} := \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if facet } f_i \text{ and polyhedron } c_j \text{ are incident and coherent,}\\
  -1 & \text{if facet } f_i \text{ and polyhedron } c_j \text{ are incident and anti-coherent,}\\
  0 & \text{else}\\
  \end{cases} $
  where the 3 dimensional cells are chosen such that two adjacent cells have opposite orientations w.r.t. any common facet. How can i prove that such a complex has trivial homology? I need Ker($B$) $=$ Im($C$) in order for the subsequent steps in the paper to hold true.

I would be happy if any of you could recommend literature on cell complexes in the context of subdivisons of compact spaces with the focus being on complexes with trivial homology. I want to better understand boundary operators and how to compute them. What puzzled me the most in the above mentioned papers is that the same facet was considered twice in 2 different orientations. I had trouble working out how this special case fits within the framework of algebraic topoogy.

Comment: This looks like it should be viewed as a CW complex, and its homology computed accordingly. See Hatcher starting on p. 137, including the "Cellular Boundary Formula" on p. 140.

Comment: Oh, and it is contractible, so all of its homology groups (in positive dimensions) should be zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I already stumbled across this formula once. However, it was quite difficult to follow the book up to this formula. Could you recommend any comprehensible entry level resources or examples where this formula was applied? I need algebraic topology only in order to be able to understand this small transformation mentioned in Leo Gradys paper. As he didn't give a formal proof to his claim and stated it somehow as a fact i thought that there is maybe a simpler way of seeing what the matrix C looks like without having to dive deep into the topic.

Comment: One way to approach this particular case is: first try to understand simplicial complexes, objects like this but where all of the $2$-cells are triangles and all of the $3$-cells are tetrahedra. Then note that in the case you're asking about, you can subdivide each polyhedron to get triangles and tetrahedra — you can turn it into a simplicial complex. Then you have to verify that the two ways of defining homology groups match up. See 7.1.15 and 7.1.16 in https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis6100/complex1.pdf for at least the start of this.